# Unable to locate ADB since the last update

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, adb

I have got a problem with Android Studio IDE.

Since the last update, when I am trying to start my app in device, IDE returns an error to me ( **Unable to locate ADB** ).

I tried reinstall platform tools. It didn't help.

I reinstalled the Android Studio. It didn't help too.

I even reinstalled Windows, but it didn't help too.

I was looking for a solution and I tried fixing it, but it isn't working.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- on your android studio go to Tools > android > SDK Manager.

2- view android SDK location (this will show you your sdk path)

3- navigate to file explorer on your system, and locate the file path, this should be found something like c://Users/xxxx/AppData/local/android (you can now see the sdk.)

4- check the platform tools folder and see if you would see anything like adb.exe (it should be missing probably because it was corrupted and your antivirus or windows defender has quarantined it)

5- delete the platform tools folder

6- go back to android studio and from where you left off navigate to sdk tools (this should be right under android sdk location)

7- uncheck android sdk platform-tools and select ok. (this will uninstall the platform tools from your ide) wait till it is done and then your gradle will sync.

8- after sync is complete, go back and check the box of android sdk platform-tools (this will install a fresh one with new adb.exe) wait till it is done and sync project and then you are good to go.

I hope this saves someone some hours of pain.

Comment: Thanks for help! My antivirus moved adb.exe to quarantine.